# flash builder 4 : flash.net.SecureSocket can not be found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have Flash Builder 4 installed. I created a new Actionscript project and when I try to import flash.net.SecureSocket, I get a compile error saying that flash.net.SecureSocket can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're working on a mobile app and there is no support for ServerSocket or Socket for that matter on mobile or for TV see the note in the top of the docs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html

That said there is an ANE out there for a Socket class for iOS, I personally plan on eventually writing one for the Android side as well as they also provide a Socket class (I have no idea why Adobe doesn't support this out of the box).